# PHP update MySQL looping

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, insert

I have the following code which updates my database with the userID, value (liked or disliked), and reminder date whenever a user 'likes' a contest (which is a post).

$query looks at my userContests table and stores it's entire contents.

The userContests table stores the userID, value (liked or disliked), contestID, and reminder date.

$getfreq is an array containing values 123, 234, 345, 456, 567

I hope the code explains itself, I've done my best to comment each section for you. The basic point here is that if $getfreq contains value 345, insert or update my database with the reminder date.

```
$userID = 1;
$value = 1;
$contestID = 1737;
if (($userID > 0) && ($contestID > 0) && ($value < 2)){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userContests WHERE userID='$userID' AND contestID='$contestID';") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $getfreq = mysql_query("
            SELECT wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
            FROM wp_term_relationships 
            WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = $contestID
        "); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfreq)) {
        if ($value == 1){ // If the contest is liked
            if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {  //if a value matching the userID and contest ID already exists in database
                 if ($row[term_taxonomy_id] == 345) { // if Daily entry, update the row with reminder date
                    echo "1";
                    mysql_query("UPDATE userContests SET value='$value', reminder= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE userID='$userID' AND contestID='$contestID';") or die(mysql_error());
                    $frequency = 'Daily';
                } else { // if anything other than above, insert the row with current date
                    echo "2";
                    mysql_query("UPDATE userContests SET value='$value', reminder= CURDATE() WHERE userID='$userID' AND contestID='$contestID';") or die(mysql_error());
                }
            } else { // if there is no previous row in database matching userID and contestID
                if ($row[term_taxonomy_id] == 345) { // if Daily entry, insert the row with reminder date
                    echo "3";
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO userContests (userID, contestID, value, reminder) VALUES ('$userID', '$contestID', '$value', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)') ") or die(mysql_error());
                } else { // if anything other than above, insert the row with current date
                    echo "4";
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO userContests (userID, contestID, value, reminder) VALUES ('$userID', '$contestID', '$value', CURDATE()) ") or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        } else if ($value == 0){ // if the value is disliked
            if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {  //if a value matching the userID and contest ID already exists in database, simply update the row without reminder
                echo "5";
                mysql_query("UPDATE userContests SET value='$value' WHERE userID='$userID' AND contestID='$contestID';") or die(mysql_error());
            } else { // if there is no previous row in database matching userID and contestID, simply insert the row without reminder
            echo "6";
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO userContests (userID, contestID, value) VALUES ('$userID', '$contestID', '$value') ") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code works. Sort of. My problem is that the insert code is inserting itself in my database 5 times. I only want it to insert once.

The echoes in the code serve for debugging. I am receiving 4 4 3 4 4 as echoes.

I know the problem is because of the loop, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

I've deduced that the reason it is inserting the code 5 times is because as the code loops, it checks to see if $row = 345. Since the first two and last two times it doesn't, the code inserts as per echo 4 while ont he 3rd loop, it inserts as per echo 3 since there is a match.

Now, I am aware of in_array() but don't know how to use it in the context of my mysql query. I suspect that this might be the solution...

Can anyone help?

Comment: you need to debug your code: use echo before every INSERT, to know which queries are executed, how many times, in which order...

Comment: See my revised question. I receive an output of 4 4 3 4 4.

Comment: your $value will never be changed, you set it as 1 and it always stays 1.

Comment: $value is set to 1 for the purpose of this example. The $value is actually set the moment the user clicks the button. $value = 1 means the post is liked.

Comment: Hold on here. How many rows are selected when processing the `$getfreq` query? Do a `mysql_num_rows()` on it to find out.

Comment: 5 rows are selected. As I mentioned, the values returned are 123, 234, 345, 456, 567. I've explained why the problem happens and I understand that the loop is behaving the way it should, the problem is I don't know the correct way to do what I want.

Comment: Okay, under `if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {` throw in `print_r($row); break;` and show me the result.

Comment: I get Array ( [term_taxonomy_id] => 123 )

Comment: Okay. Now undo what you just did and do the same again, but this time, throw in `echo "Is 345<br>"` instead of `print_r($row); break;`

Comment: Right. So this all comes back down to your `$getfreq` query. That query returns 5 results. Which is why your `while` loop is looping 5 times. So your code is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. If you limit the query to only grab one row (result) then the code will only affect that single row. Which is probably not what you want. Right?

Comment: Right, but I can't do that because the query cannot discriminate. My code should be looking inside the array to see if it contains 345. If it does, execute code. If it doesn't, do something else. This is where I think in_array() should come in a replace my loop entirely, but I don't know how to get it to work with my $getfreq array.

Comment: Right, so do when you say 'do something else' : by that, do you mean other INSERT queries, or just some other stuff?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. You say if something is 345 do an `insert` query, and if not still do an `insert` query...so either way, something will be inserted into the table. Yet, your problem is that something is inserted every time...which is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have an error in the loop.

You just never update any of the variables, that you have in the inserting SQL.

I mean - you say you have 5 values in $getfreq, the third one is 345 and therefore the branch with "3" will happen, in all the other cases, the branch with "4" will happen. None of the other variables are changed, ever.

You get into this branch

```
           if ($row[term_taxonomy_id] == 345) { // if Daily entry, insert the row with reminder date
                echo "3";
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO userContests (userID, contestID, value, reminder) VALUES ('$userID', '$contestID', '$value', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)') ") or die(mysql_error());
            } else { // if anything other than above, insert the row with current date
                echo "4";
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO userContests (userID, contestID, value, reminder) VALUES ('$userID', '$contestID', '$value', CURDATE()) ") or die(mysql_error());
            }
```

In the third case, it gets into the "3" branch and is inserted.

However, in all the other cases, this line is executed

```
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO userContests (userID, contestID, value, reminder) VALUES ('$userID', '$contestID', '$value', CURDATE()) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

because you have it in `else` branch.

If you don't want to do the loop at all and just want to check once, you will have to do something like this.

```
$getfreq = mysql_query("
        SELECT COUNT(taxonomy_id) AS freq
        FROM wp_term_relationships 
        WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = $contestID
         AND wp_term_relationshis.taxonomy_id = 345
    ");    

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfreq);

if ($data['freq'] > 1) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

I hope I wrote it correctly since I am doig it from top of my head :)

If you want to check for more than one value, try this:

```
$getfreq = mysql_query("
        SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id
        FROM wp_term_relationships 
        WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = $contestID
    ");    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfreq)) {
    $taxonomy_id = $row[term_taxonomy_id];
    $seen[$taxonomy_id] = 1;
}

if ($seen[334]) {
   //something
} else if ($seen[456]) {
   //something else
} else {
   //last branch
}
```

Comment: Exactly. I want to know how to avoid using a loop. Instead I want to look inside $getfreq and see if it contains 345. If it does, execute branch 3. If it doesn't execute branch 4.

Comment: Yes, I know what you're saying. I am asking for a way to avoid using the loop altogether and instead use in_array().

Comment: Oh, but that completely changes the situation. Wait, I will edit it once more

Comment: It's close. The problem is what if I want to do different things if 345 is found or if 567 is found? Making a bunch of MySQL queries is inefficient when I could use in_array() to look in $getfreq instead.

Comment: an advice: better explain what you actually want next time you are asking.

Comment: I don't know how much clearer "how can I use in_array() instead of my loop" can be... but duely noted.

Comment: don't take it personal :) but just take a look at your problem from the other side, from a person that doesn't have a clue what is your code about and what it wants to do. The more you explain the better. good luck

Comment: Your answer if ultimately the one that prevails. array_search() fails if I add a branch t the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is becoming overly confusing, but I'm taking a flying guess.

You want to do a search in the result set for the '345' entry and if it's found, do something, and if not, do something else, right?

Well, either way, here's how to do that, with `array_search();`:

```
$resultSet= mysql_get_assoc($getfreq);

if ( array_search(345,$resultSet) !== false )
{

# - 345 Is here!!! -

//do what you gotta do...


}

else
{

# - 345 is not in $resultSet -

//do something else here

}
```

Comment: Good to know xD But in future mate, you should really explain your question in better terms. I was beginning to think this is one of those wind-up question that trolls post just to annoy the kind users here who are willing to help...

Comment: Alright. But I did mention that I thought in_array() was the solution and no one was picking up on that. Your method is much simpler, with fewer lines of code.

Comment: Well, I did stop reading the question as soon as you explained the issue. So fair enough.

Comment: @navnav: hah, I didn't know it is possible to get all results to one array and search in that. That is cool. One can learn even on other people questions :)

Comment: @KarelBílek Nice. Be careful though! `array_search()` can trick you. How? If it finds the value in the array, it wont return `true`, but instead, the key of the element that the value was found in. So lets say you have this array: `$arr=array('nav','bob')` and you use `array_search()` to grab 'nav', it will return `0` as `0` is the indexed key of the element that the value ('nav') was found in. But, what else `== 0`? `false`. So if you did `if(array_search('nav',$arr) == false)`, that condition would be true, even though there was a match found. (ALWAYS USE `===` with `array_search`)

Comment: Ultimately, this solution fails when adding another branch to the if statement.